# Discord Bot, Why does it remain offline ? [Noob]

Tags: node.js

I've followed [this tutorial](https://medium.com/davao-js/tutorial-creating-a-simple-discord-bot-9465a2764dc0).

I've got 3 files :

package.json

```
{
"name": "greeter-bot",
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "My own Discord bot",
"main": "bot.js",
"author": "YOUR-NAME-HERE",
 "dependencies": {}
}
```

auth.json

```
{
   "token": "Abcde123blahblah"
}
```

bot.js

```
var Discord = require('discord.io');
var logger = require('winston');
var auth = require('./auth.json');
// Configure logger settings
logger.remove(logger.transports.Console);
logger.add(logger.transports.Console, {
    colorize: true
});
logger.level = 'debug';
// Initialize Discord Bot
var bot = new Discord.Client({
   token: auth.token,
   autorun: true
});
bot.on('ready', function (evt) {
    logger.info('Connected');
    logger.info('Logged in as: ');
    logger.info(bot.username + ' - (' + bot.id + ')');
});
bot.on('message', function (user, userID, channelID, message, evt) {
    // Our bot needs to know if it will execute a command
    // It will listen for messages that will start with `!`
    if (message.substring(0, 1) == '!') {
        var args = message.substring(1).split(' ');
        var cmd = args[0];

        args = args.splice(1);
        switch(cmd) {
        // !ping
            case 'ping':
                bot.sendMessage({
                    to: channelID,
                    message: 'Pong!'
                });
            break;
            // Just add any case commands if you want to..
         }
     }
});
```

Installed dependencies :

```
npm install discord.io winston --save
```

Finally, using

```
node bot.js
```

should run my bot, if I understand correctly. Sadly it remains offline on the server. Anything I missed ?

Thanks !

Comment: Without seeing your code or even the output of the program there's no way for us to know if there's something you've missed.

Comment: AH sorry I only posted the link of the tutorial. I've now added the whole code directly here

Comment: auth.json should be updated with your own token?

Comment: I have done that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you missed this part of the tutorial where it shows you how to get your token in `auth.json` (under the `auth.json` section). `'YOUR-BOT-TOKEN'` is not going to work.

-----> [guide](https://github.com/reactiflux/discord-irc/wiki/Creating-a-discord-bot-&-getting-a-token)

EDIT: Also, the OP needed these additional dependencies to get the above code from the tutorial to work (see [this github discussion](http://%20github.com/renesansz/discord-greeter-bot/issues/88)):

`npm install discord.io github:woor/discord.io#gateway_v6 winston --save`

Comment: Any luck? I see in the github issues that the author points to at the bottom of his tutorial suggest success after running `npm install discord.io github:woor/discord.io#gateway_v6 winston --save`

Comment: issues such as https://github.com/renesansz/discord-greeter-bot/issues/88 sound like yours and were solved by the above install

Comment: Yes, perfect. Thank you

Comment: Cool, I added that last bit into the answer, can you accept the answer so that others can know this was what fixed it? Thank you.